# How to write a macro to get source file name without directories?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I want to make a string value that contains current source file name (`__FILE__` without directories) and can be transferred into a debug output method.

I tried the following inline function:

```
inline string GetFileWithoutDir() {
    path p(__FILE__);
    return p.filename().string();
}
```

But `inline` is not guaranteed to be expanded, so `__FILE__` may not be the caller's source file, right?

Macros are guaranteed to be expanded, but `GetFileWithoutDir` has multiple statements. How can I fit these two lines into a single macro?

Comment: `inline` doesn't do what you seem to think it does

Comment: `__FILE__` is the file containing the function's definition. It's not the name of the file that's the "root" of the current translation unit or the file that's including the definition. And `inline` ain't got nothing to do with function inlining no more.